# Weird behavior with Restlet and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, restlet

I have the following piece of code with `Restlet` in `Google AppEngine` from an Android client.

```
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource(RESTLET_TEST_URL);
ProductResource productResource = clientResource.wrap(ProductResource.class);
productResource.store(mProduct);
Status status = clientResource.getResponse().getStatus();
Toast.makeText(this, "Status: "+ status.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
clientResource.release();
```

The `.store()` method is analogous to a PUT request. The weird thing is, this works fine when I connect to the  development server but on the actual AppEngine site, nothing happens. I just get `Status: OK` indicating that the request went through.

I can't troubleshoot cause I can only do that in the Dev Server and that is working fine.

Any ideas on what the problem may be or how to approach this ?

For reference, the code at the server end is :

```
if (product != null ) {
    if (new DataStore().putToDataStore(product) ) {
    log.warning("Product written to datastore");
} else {
        log.warning("Product not found in datastore");
    }
}
```

This is just a simple write to the datastore using `Objectify`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a known issue. See [here](http://restlet.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1219)

The solution is to use `clientResource.setEntityBuffering(true);`. However, please note that this method is only available in the Release Candidate for Android Client and not in the stable release.